# log error with passenger in rails 6 app : set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a rails 6 app, working fine, using passenger with nginx, but there is log error like this :

```
App 759213 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (www-data) and Ruby interpreter...
App 759213 output:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 759213 output:      Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
App 759213 output:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-gdcb4x.log
App 759213 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 759213 output:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 759213 output:      Could not download https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/download/release-6.0.19/rubyext-ruby-3.0.6-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
App 759213 output:      Trying next mirror...
App 759213 output:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.19/rubyext-ruby-3.0.6-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
App 759213 output:      Trying next mirror...
App 759213 output:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.19/rubyext-ruby-3.0.6-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
App 759213 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 759213 output:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
App 759253 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (www-data) and Ruby interpreter...
App 759253 output:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 759253 output:      Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
App 759253 output:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-8s1xwa.log
App 759253 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 759253 output:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 759253 output:      Could not download https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/download/release-6.0.19/rubyext-ruby-3.0.6-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
App 759253 output:      Trying next mirror...
App 759253 output:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.19/rubyext-ruby-3.0.6-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
App 759253 output:      Trying next mirror...
App 759253 output:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.19/rubyext-ruby-3.0.6-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
App 759253 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 759253 output:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
App 759384 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (www-data) and Ruby interpreter...
App 759384 output:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 759384 output:      Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
App 759384 output:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-1dlu9gp.log
```

So why? and how resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install `curl` or `wget`

Comment: both are already installed....

Comment: Well those error messages are telling you that the process in question can't find them.

Comment: yes but I dont know why, I can use them... maybe passenger don't have permission? how can I test this?

Comment: You need to try running them as the user your passenger is running as, using `sudo`. You might need them in a different location so they're in that user's PATH, or you might need to add some config to add to that user's PATH env var.

Comment: nginx using www-data, but I dont know how see the PATH for this user or update it. Do you know the cmd to do all this?